# New to HTML/PHP - trying to host site on a server, but when I go to link of my site, I get a directory of my own folders?

Tags: php, html, cyberduck

Yup, so that’s my question.

I am really new to html/php/web programming in general.

I am uploading my files on cyberduck - when I upload the html files, they get converted from code to actual text and images which are not even displayed properly. I think I’ve chmod’ed all my images, yet rather than images that show up, I get clickable text.

I am massively sorry if these sound like silly questions, but i would be really appreciative of any help!

Comment: do you have an index file?

Comment: Sounds like you're either uploading as a non `.php` or a non `.html` file, or your server is serving the files as eg. `Content-type: text/plain`. Could you check the response HTTP header with a tool like Fiddler2 (for windows), so you can see what `content-type` your server tells you that the document is in?

Comment: They don't sound like silly questions, but they're not actually questions. ("I get a directory of my own folders" is a statement, not a question, whether you put a question mark after it or not.) Aside from that, could you provide a link to one of these HTML files you've uploaded?

Comment: Thanks for the replies! I do have an index file, but I realize (sheepishly) now that it was in the wrong folder - so my site link now actually goes to the site.

Comment: All my files are indeed just .php and .html, but I will check the HTTP response now.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you've got a file called `index` with an extension of `.html` `.htm` or `.php`
2. You shouldn't allow directory listing (unless you really want to), to remove this option you should add the line `Options -Indexes` to your `.htaccess` file. If you don't have such a file you can easily create one and upload it.

Comment: Thanks for the help again! After fiddling around with my project, I realize my header.php code is problematic because every time I save it as a plaintext file header.php, I lose the code and get what I should have gotten on the site:

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html><html>
    <head>
        <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <?php if (isset($title)): ?>
            <title>Site: <?= htmlspecialchars($title) ?></title>
        <?php else: ?>
            <title>SiteName</title>
        <?php endif ?>
    </head>

Comment: <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
         <div id="top">
                <a href="/"><img alt=“Image1" src="img/logo.gif"/></a>
            </div>
            <div id="top">
            <a href="/"><img alt="Border" src="img/line.gif"/></a>
                <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                    <li><a href=“file1.php"><b>Link1</b></a></li>
                    <li><a href=“file2.php"><b>Link2</b></a></li>
                </ul>
            <a href="/"><img alt="Border" src="img/line.gif"/></a>
            </div>
            <div id="middle">